# In the phrase "there's a good film on late", does "on" mean "on TV"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> There’s a good film on late.

Usually, at the end of "there's something" or "there are some things", a specific thing follows the "there" in front.

I surmise after "on", TV is hidden. If I am correct, why TV is omitted here?

Comment: I find your example "peculiar". In my neck of the woods, we'd either say *There's a good film on **late tonight*** OR more likely ***...later*** OR ***...later tonight***. As an answer to the question *What are you doing tonight?,* I wouldn't expect, say, *I'm going down the pub **late*** (but I *would* accept *I'm going to a disco, so **I'll be home late***).

Comment: You should also note that *in context*, your speaker might be talking about a movie that's being screened late tonight ***at the local cinema*** (or some streaming website, that you intend to watch on your smartphone later).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your another aspect of my question: late, later + tonight, be home late

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yet "I'm going to the pub, I'll be home late" is perfectly fine. All other examples provided here, both by you and the OP, are the same usage. It's just that some of these are more commonly used than others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "on late" is entirely OK in colloquial UK English.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: Maybe for you. Not for me, as I explained. *The shop is **open late*** and *The film is **on late*** aren't directly comparable, because the shop is probably already open, but the film probably isn't currently on. Whereas *The shop is open later* and *The film is on later* are normally comparable, in that neither subject is yet in its predicted future state.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But neither are "the train arrived late" or "my visitor left late" directly comparable with "a film on late" which is the subject of OP's question. I agree that "late" has to be qualified by something to get adequate context, but "on later" can just as easily refer to a child's Saturday Morning cartoon as to the parents' late-night thriller.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: I don't claim that you have to accept my ideas about what's idiomatically natural in this context. I think what I think, and you can do likewise. If you think *I'm going down the pub late* and *I hope there's a good film on late* are "natural" phrasing, all I can say is *not for me!* Appeals to "syntactic rules" are irrelevant here - it's just a matter of what individual speakers do or don't find idiomatic.

Comment: Agree with @FumbleFingers that in certain situations it doesn't sound natural.

Comment: *I'll see you later* - fine. *I'll see you late tonight* - fine. *I'll see you late* - slightly weird (for me, at least. ymmd).

Comment: Couldn't the sentence also mean "there's a good film on these days" ?

Comment: @theonlygusti It can't be due to the 'late'.

Comment: @gomadeng It's precisely because of the late that it sounds like it could also have that meaning. Short for either "as of late" or "lately"

Comment: on [during the] late[night television slot]. *on late* is a noun phrase and somewhere here in a deleted answer because Google says there should be 4 answers here not 2. "The extra noun phrase is set apart prosodically from the rest of the clause" IDK what that means, but there it is.

Comment: Descriptive adjective? Phase of some sort, with a bunch of words missing? It means *scheduled* but that's not what its abbreviating. *late[night television]* which was when you can swear and shit and show boobs. Now it's N/A.

Answer (score 26):

In this sentence "on" is not short for "on TV". Here it means "scheduled". It is the same use of "on" as in "What have you got on tonight? - I have a meeting at 7:30".

If you are at home then it will be assumed that the film will be shown using the TV.

If you were at a shopping centre with a cinema, the sentence could mean that the cinema would be showing a good film at a late screening.

Comment: Or it could be a theatre show, or a sports game, or, or... 

Comment: *What have you got on tonight?* - eh, manners please.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. But "on" need not be a preposition. [It can have various syntactic functions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Adverb): preposition, part of a phrasal verb, adverb. In this case (says Wiktionary) it's an adverb, and no complement to the preposition is expected.

Here are some more examples where it seems adverbial (with various different meanings):

> Anything good on?
> *Is anything good being played on the radio or TV or stage?*

> Why's the TV on?
> *Why is the TV running?*

> What's on for tonight?
> *What has been planned?*

> Soup's on!
> *The soup is ready to eat!*

Comment: These other meanings of "on" have nothing to do with the meaning in the OP's example sentence. "To be on" isn't a phrasal verb. It's "be" and the word "on".

Comment: @gotube Indeed they have nothing to do with the meaning, but the meaning is dealt with in the first three words of my answer, and then I move on to OP's second question. As for the phrasal verb, I'll amend.

Comment: What other question did the OP ask? I don't see anything asking for a list of uses of "on" in general, and such a question would be off-topic for being too broad anyway.

Comment: @gotube "I surmise after 'on', TV is hidden. If I am correct, why TV is omitted here?" The intent is to show that nothing is necessarily omitted because the surmise is not necessarily correct. (This does imply that I disagree with your answer. The fact that sometimes one could supply a complement to the preposition doesn't mean what we have here is a preposition with something omitted, just as "let's go inside" just means "let's go indoors", without omitting some context-dependent complement for what one will be inside.)

Comment: Of course, it comes to the same thing, but I prefer not to posit an element thought of and deleted. It doesn't accord with my intuition of how I form such sentences, though it may with yours.